# May "get" be used instead of "hire"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use `get (a) doctor, get lawer, get security guard`
instead of `hire (a) doctor, hire lawer, hire security guard` in sentence 
if the person's services are used temporarly, on a contract basis?

Comment: What's the context for the usage?

Comment: Check the dictionary definitions. ***Hiring*** a professional always implies ***paying*** for his services, but in many societies you can ***get*** state-funded medical / legal / etc. services without having to actually pay for them at time of need.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter whether it's temporary or permanent, the use of get is correct. But the indefinite article is not optional.

Get a doctor, lawyer or security guard.

Get a doctor, get a lawyer, get a security guard.

Answer (score 0):

"Get" and "hire" are both correct and often used in this context. Neither of them implies anything about the temporary or permanent nature of such relationships, or how such relationships are financially formed. They both simply mean "obtain service," and leave all the details unaddressed.

"Get" is casual. I wouldn't expect to find it in formal or business writing, but I hear it in day-to-day conversations all the time.

"Hire" subtly places an emphasis on the financial aspect of the relationship. This is less common in describing medical relationships, so "hire a doctor" is not nearly as common as "get a doctor." With lawyers and guards, however, it's completely ordinary.